# How can I make a horizontally sliding image on a website?

Tags: html, css, mobile

So I've been trying for a few days to get this to work but I'm no closer.
I'm making a website and at the top I'm trying to get a square image, a map to be specific, that's as wide, and tall, as the viewport height.  Naturally the image is centered. Thats the easy part but I'm struggling to make it in such a way that you can drag/slide the image to the right or left to see the rest of the map.

The attached gif should help explain, with the green square being the image, the rectangle being the screen/viewpoint, and the grey circle being a tap and swipe motion that moves the image.
[animated example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHzOX.gif)

I've tried a good few ways to make an image carousel but nothing has worked the way I'd like.
I'm trying to get it to slide horizontally smoothly without snapping to a set position.

Here's the code I've tried, it works perfectly except when you try moving it into the centre, the below example uses `transform: translate` bus I've also tried `position: relative` with `left: -50%`. In both cases you can't scroll to the left and when you scroll to the right the image doesn't stop at the edge and leaves a bad looking white gap.

```html
    <div class="d1">
      <img src="square-image.jpeg">
    </div>
```

```css
    .d1 {
      border: 3px solid red;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .d1 img {
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      transform: translate(-20%, 0);
    }
```

(Yes that is mostly the code from the answer below but it's just a lot neater than what I was trying before and I've added it in retrospect for anyone else with a similar question.)

I'd greatly appreciate any help, even a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: please add your code to your question ... explain how it failed

Comment: @jsotola You're completely right, I've changed the title. As for the code, it's just an image with style  `position: absolute;` and `left: -25%;` to center it, but that can be done by any means. As for the sliding, to be perfectly honest I'm completely stumped, but I know there's probably something really simple I'm unaware of.

Comment: If you are wondering why people are downvoting your question, it's because you haven't provided any of the code you have written. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, so we are very suspicious of "how do I do X" questions which don't contain any evidence that you have attempted it yourself first. If you edit your question to include the code you have tried, people are more likely to look kindly upon your question.

Comment: @BrettDonald thanks for the tip, I've added the latest code I've tried, based off one of the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `overflow: auto` on your map’s parent element to enable you to drag/scroll/pan the map sideways.

Here I have used a `<div>` element as the map’s parent to illustrate the technique, but if your map’s parent is the `<body>` element you could apply `overflow: auto` to that instead.

I am using Javascript to set the scroll position of the parent so that the map will be centered within the ‘viewport’ and can be scrolled left or right.

```js
const d1 = document.querySelector('.d1')
d1.scrollLeft = (d1.scrollWidth - d1.clientWidth) / 2;
```

```css
.d1 {
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 188px;
  height: 406px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.d1 img {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <img src="https://www.worldatlas.com/r/w1200/upload/08/4d/54/au-01.png">
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly and makes me feel rather stupid for not knowing about it... Thank you very much Brett, I've marked the answer as correct